# How to Upload Sitemap xml to Google webmaster tools Using ASP.Net/C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-search-console, google-api-dotnet-client

Can anyone help me to upload a `sitemap.xml` file to `Google webmaster tools` using coding like C#. I need to generate my site xml dynamically and then to upload to webmaster tools.

Comment: Welcome to stack: What have you tried? maybe something along this lines? https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sitemaps/submit